# How to create custom Entity / Attributes in core data programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am making a program to learn core data in that i am downloading data from a website having too many products .

I want to name every product as entity name .

Every product has different specification sheet (very few has common entries).

I want the product specification title to be stores as attributes and its specification detail in the corresponding attribute.

I am having array of product list , specification title, specification.

I am trying to search to create entity programmatically from past 2 days no luck , nothing understood/worked what I have found.

Comment: Core Data doesn't work that way - you need to create a static Core Data model.  From your description, one approach you could take is to create a Product entity that had the basics like product name, description etc and another entity called "Attributes" with a "name" and "value" with a one to many relationship from "Product" to "Attributes"

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create an entity for every single product. That's bad practice. Create one entity named Product and add the name as an attribute together with all the other attributes.
For the different specification details you could create and Detail-Entity and add a To-Many-Relationship in the product entity.

Comment: So can I add dynamic attributes ?
Because I don't know how many attributes is required because some has 10 some hase 20 and all has different names.

Comment: Yes, that's what "to-many" means. If you click on the attribute-relationship in your product-entity in your .xcdatamodeld you can set a type in the data model inspector on the right side of xcode. choose "to many". then your product can have multiple attributes.

Comment: Thank you for showing me where I should go.
I will now study and learn relationship and how to deal with them.